# Include menu into html files

Tags: html, css, include

I have a web site of more than 20 pages, all using the same `dropdown` menu. Currently, each page contains redundant HTML code for the menu, so if I want to change one thing in a menu, I have to change it for all the pages. I am using plain `html/css` and some `javascript` for my site. Is there a way to have my `dropdown` menu all in one file and include the reference to that file for all 20 pages?

I tried using the `<embed>` element to include the menu, but it did not work out for me since I cannot adequately align it as it leaves a large empty area right below it to allow for `dropdown` options. Not sure what is the best way to handle that

Comment: You could use the PHP include statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Quetin Veron in the comment, PHP include statements are the best way to deal with it.

However, in case you're not interested in writing backend code, you can do that using JavaScript by parsing a json or an ini file/text in your script and converting it into the required links on the menu.

**[Do note that you'll still have to use JavaScript for that]**

If you'd not even prefer to use JS (Not recommended), you can use an `iframe` as the navigation menu

When you do that, add `<base target="_parent">` in the `head` section of your iframe.
And then, in all other pages, add `<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>` and replace `menu.html` with the path to the menu.

I hope this helps. However, please note that this just is a workaround if you wish to use frontend technologies only.

Otherwise use `<?php include "menu.php";?>` for PHP or for Node with EJS, use `<%include "menu.ejs";%>`